# How do I merge/expand two python pandas dataframes, based on one common column but different content?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

I would like to merge two data frames but I don't get the right result.
df1 like this:

```
         Date Name1
0  2018-08-05   abc
1  2019-08-05  cdsx
2  2020-08-05  sdfs
```

df2 like this

```
         Date  Name2
0  2017-06-02  dfdds
1  2018-09-17   hger
```

I want to merge these two data frames and get a df3 like this:

```
         Date Name1  Name2
0  2017-06-02   NaN  dfdds
1  2018-08-05   abc    NaN
2  2018-09-17   NaN   hger
3  2019-08-05  cdsx    NaN
4  2020-08-05  sdfs    NaN
```

df1 and df2 have a common column: Date, but there is no same information.

I tried to use 'merge', but I didn't get the right result.

Can anyone give me some suggestions to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use **outer** [merge](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.merge.html) with `sort=True`:

```
print( pd.merge(df1, df2, on='Date', how='outer', sort=True) )
```

Prints:

```
        Date Name1  Name2
0 2017-06-02   NaN  dfdds
1 2018-08-05   abc    NaN
2 2018-09-17   NaN   hger
3 2019-08-05  cdsx    NaN
4 2020-08-05  sdfs    NaN
```